# A header in a table with two lines

Tags: tables

The following code has `LaTeX` make a table.  In the header, I want "End of the" over "kth week"in the first column and "Total Number of" over "Copies Sold" in the second column.

```
    \documentclass{amsart}

    \usepackage{adjustbox}\usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{array}\usepackage{makecell}\usepackage{stackengine}\setstackEOL{\cr} %EOL is abbreviation for "end of line."

    \begin{document}

    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}\stackon{%
\begin{tabular}{|| c | c||} \hline
End of the \textit{k}\textsuperscript{th} week  &   Total Number of Copies Sold \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
k=1 &   3200 \\ \hline
k=2 &   5500 \\ \hline
k=3 &   6800 \\ \hline
k=4 &   7400 \\ \hline
k=5 &   7700 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
{\bfseries\Longstack{Sales of Book \textit{A}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you want the alignment of the split header cell parts?  Centered or left (or right)?

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes  Please show me the code for the display to have the text in the split header cells centered and include a comment to have the text flush left or flush right.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy with the `\thead` command from `makecell`. I took the opportunity to improve your table with `\hhline` and changed the value of `stackdap`, as the  title was much too close to the first `\hline`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{adjustbox}\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}\setstackEOL{\cr}%EOL is abbreviation for "end of line."
\setstackgap{S}{2ex}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\begin{document}

\stackon{\makegapedcells%
    \begin{tabular}{|| c | c||}
        \hline
        \thead{End of the & \\\textit{k}\textsuperscript{th} week} & \thead{Total Number of\\ Copies Sold} \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
        $ k=1 $ & 3200 \\ \hhline{||--||}
        $ k=2 $ & 5500 \\ \hhline{||--||}
        $ k=3 $ & 6800 \\ \hhline{||--||}
        $ k=4 $ & 7400 \\ \hhline{||--||}
        $ k=5 $ & 7700 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
{\bfseries\Longstack{Sales of Book \textit{A}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{adjustbox}\usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr} %EOL is abbreviation for "end of line."

    \begin{document}

    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}\stackon{%
\begin{tabular}{|| c | c||} \hline
\thead{End of the\\ \textit{k}\textsuperscript{th} week}
    &   \thead{Total Number of\\ Copies Sold} \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
k=1 &   3200 \\ \hline
k=2 &   5500 \\ \hline
k=3 &   6800 \\ \hline
k=4 &   7400 \\ \hline
k=5 &   7700 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
{\bfseries\Longstack{Sales of Book \textit{A}}}

\end{document}
```

Many people have opinion, that table are more beautiful if they hasn't vertical lines:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{adjustbox}\usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{makecell,booktabs}
    \usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr} %EOL is abbreviation for "end of line."

    \begin{document}

    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}\stackon{%
\begin{tabular}{c c} 
    \toprule
\thead{End of the\\ \textit{k}\textsuperscript{th} week}
    &   \thead{Total Number of\\ Copies Sold} \\ 
    \midrule
k=1 &   3200 \\ 
k=2 &   5500 \\ 
k=3 &   6800 \\ 
k=4 &   7400 \\ 
k=5 &   7700 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
{\bfseries\Longstack{Sales of Book \textit{A}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I suggest you  make th last version still nicer using two `\cmidrule` instead of one `midrule`?

Comment: @Bernard   To what package does `\thead` belong?  Does it just allow two lines?  What does `midrule` instruct `LaTeX` to draw?  What is the difference between `cmidrule` and `midrule`?

Comment: @Bernard, with which option do you think that ``cmidrule`` will be nicer than ``midrule``?

Comment: `\thead` is from `makecell`. The difference between `\midrule` and `\cmidrule` is the same as between `\hline` and `\cline`: it draws rules across a selected number of columns, instead of the whole table.

Comment: @Zarko: `\cmidrule` can be trimmed at both ends (independently), so  two\cmidrules can be separated by a small space. Try `\cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}`, you'll see how it looks like.

Comment: Now I see, what is the point of your comment. In a case, when table haven't vertical lines, as I show in second example, when is not need for separate narrower horizontal lines for each column, ``midrule`` is just fin, isn't it?.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I split the header using a stack.  The OP asked in a comment how one would define the alignment of the split header.  I show it centered, but add this line in the code, that will define the alignment of the split headers lines:

```
\renewcommand\stackalignment{c}% <--- USE l,c, OR r TO SET SPLIT HEADER
```

The headers will be centered with respect to the data, as given by the `{|c|c|}` argument to the `tabular`, but the individual rows of the header will be aligned according to the above `\stackalignment` setting.

The full MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{adjustbox}\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}\setstackEOL{\cr} %EOL is abbreviation for "end of line."

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}\stackon{%
\renewcommand\stackalignment{c}% <--- USE l,c, OR r TO SET SPLIT HEADER ALIGNMENT
\begin{tabular}{|| c | c||} \hline
\stackanchor{End of the}{\textit{k}\textsuperscript{th} week}  &  
\addstackgap{\stackanchor{Total Number of}{Copies Sold}} \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
k=1 &   3200 \\ \hline
k=2 &   5500 \\ \hline
k=3 &   6800 \\ \hline
k=4 &   7400 \\ \hline
k=5 &   7700 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
{\bfseries\Longstack{Sales of Book \textit{A}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need `\renewcommand` in `\renewcommand\stackalignment{c}`?  Is `\stackalignment` a command in the package `array`,  `makecell`, or `stackengine`?

Comment: I don't plan to do much more with tables than the coding that you and Bernard have provided.  I would like to pick one style and be consistent.

Comment: @user74973 `\stackalignment` is a `stackengine` definition that takes on one of 3 valid values: `l`, `c`, or `r` and defines the default horizontal alignment of any stack that follows.  In order to reset the definition, one uses either `\renewcommand` or `\def`.

Comment: @user74973  The reason I chose (being the package author) to force the use of `\def` or `\renewcommand` to redefine it, is that it allows the use of `\stackalignment` as a macro argument, which will output the single letter of `l`, `c`, or `r`.  For example, I can say `\ShortStack[\stackalignment]{a\cr bbbb}` with the provided syntax, which I could not do if `\stackalignment` were a macro that took an argument to actually set the alignment.